# How can i update a column in a SQL table if the entry is a duplicate and keep the newest entry?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a database table with about 90 thousand entries. I need to update any older entries so i can move them to an archive table. I was able to find the duplicates where the count is greater than 1 and also find out how many times it was duplicated.

This is query I used for this to work.

```
 SELECT DWPAGECOUNT, DOCTYPE, FILENAME, First, middleinitial, last, 
     COUNT(*) as Number_of_Duplicates
   FROM dbo.REGISTRAR
  WHERE first IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY DWPAGECOUNT, DOCTYPE, FILENAME, First, middleinitial, last
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ORDER by Number_of_Duplicates desc
```

I now need to update anything that is on the table more than once and leave the newest entry intact and update a status column to duplicate.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Table structure would help - what is duplicate. how is the "newest" row marked as such?

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT DWPAGECOUNT, DOCTYPE, FILENAME, First, middleinitial, last, 
    [STATUS],
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (
           PARTITION BY 
             DWPAGECOUNT, DOCTYPE, FILENAME, First, middleinitial, last
           ORDER BY 
             STOREDATETIME DESC
         )
  FROM dbo.REGISTRAR
)
UPDATE x SET [STATUS] = CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN 'DUP' ELSE 'NOT DUP' END;
```

Comment: There is a field that has the date and time of when the entry was inserted.

Comment: @user2066533 ok, what is that column called?

Comment: The name of the column is STOREDATETIME

Comment: @user2066533 and what column indicates it is a duplicate? And why not just perform the archive at runtime instead of marking a column and *then* performing the archive?

Comment: The following columns are all duplicates  -> DWPAGECOUNT, DOCTYPE, FILENAME, First, middleinitial, last.. I need to mark the older duplicates for a couple of weeks so they know not to look at them, Once they have been marked for a couple of weeks I need to take them out of the table and either delete them or move them to an archive table.

Comment: @user2066533 *sigh* you said: `update a status column to duplicate` - what is the name of that column, and how do you mark it as duplicate?

Comment: The name of the column is STATUS. if there is an older entry I would like to update the value of the STATUS column to DUP or something that the users know now to use for now.

Comment: Ok I'm done pulling teeth so I'm making a guess at what you want in the `STATUS` column for the newest entry.